# python import and return multiple result to main program

Tags: python-3.x

Here's my part of little program for testing (will be in further used)

`main.py`

```
import requests
import re
import os
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from flask import Flask, request, abort
#from imgurpython import ImgurClient
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from linebot import (
    LineBotApi, WebhookHandler
)
from linebot.exceptions import (
    InvalidSignatureError
)
from linebot.models import *

from apple_news import apple_newss

a=input("plz:")

if a == "applenews":
    content0 = apple_newss_content0
    content1 = apple_newss_content1
    content2 = apple_newss_content2
    print (content0)
    print (content1)
    print (content2)
```

and my sub program

`apple_news.py`

```
def apple_newss( apple_newss_content0, apple_newss_content1, apple_newss_content2):

    target_url = 'http://www.appledaily.com.tw/realtimenews/section/new/'
    print('Start parsing appleNews....')
    rs = requests.session()
    res = rs.get(target_url, verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

    list_links = [] # Create empty list

    for a in soup.select("div[class='abdominis rlby clearmen']")[0].findAll(href=True): # find links based on div
            if a['href']!= None and a['href'].startswith('https://'):
                    list_links.append(a['href']) #append to the list
                    print(a['href']) #Check links

#for l in list_links: # print list to screen (2nd check)
#    print(l)


    print("\n")

    random_list = [] #create random list if needed..
    random.shuffle(list_links) #random shuffle the list
    apple_newss_content0 = ''
    apple_newss_content1 = ''
    apple_newss_content2 = ''
    for i in range(3): # specify range (5 items in this instance)
        res = list_links.pop(random.randint(1, len(list_links))) # pop of each item randomly based on the size of the list
        random_list.append(res)
    #print(res)
    #print(random_list)
    print("\n")
    apple_newss_content0=random_list[0]
    apple_newss_content1=random_list[1]
    apple_newss_content2=random_list[2]
```

I just can't figure out how to return 
`apple_newss_content0` `apple_newss_content1` `apple_newss_content2`
to  `main.py`
(for some purpose  it must be in separated form  which is 3 link actually)

And make `main.py` print those 3 individually

(I've stuck this question for month.....)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your question, you can simple do

```
def apple_newss():
    apple_newss_content0 = 0
    apple_newss_content1, apple_newss_content2 = 1, 2
    return apple_newss_content0, apple_newss_content1, apple_newss_content2
```

then in main.py:

```
content0, content1, content2 = apple_newss()
```

eg.

```
>>> def apple_newss():
...     apple_newss_content0 = 0
...     apple_newss_content1, apple_newss_content2 = 1, 2
...     return apple_newss_content0, apple_newss_content1, apple_newss_content2
...
>>> content0, content1, content2 = apple_newss()
>>> content0, content1, content2
(0, 1, 2)
>>> print(content0)
0
>>> print(content1)
1
>>> print(content2)
2
```

Comment: Thanks for you help~